# Выводит вместо слов их код, как исправить?

Tags: php, dom

Выводит вместо слов их код. Как это можно исправить?

```
&#1059;&#1090;&#1086;&#1095;&#1085;&#1080;&#1090;&#1100; &#1094;&#1077;&#1085;&#1091
```

Сохраняю данные в файл с помощью команды
`file_put_contents ( 'zend.php', $ dom-> saveHTML ());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [html_entity_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.html-entity-decode.php)

```
$str = '&#1059;&#1090;&#1086;&#1095;&#1085;&#1080;&#1090;&#1100; &#1094;&#1077;&#1085;&#1091';

echo html_entity_decode($str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам необходимо перед сохранением преобразовать кодировку символов

```
echo mb_convert_encoding('&#1059;', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```